# PHP: Upgrade Google drive API from V1 to V2 or newer

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, upgrade, google-api-php-client

I am using Google API client 2.0 and want to upgrade Google drive API from V1 to V2 to newer. I not found any straight forward way to upgrade version. Only the change log from google developer site found. Please tell me upgrade process guideline or step by step process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand your question.   Are you using the [V2 of the Google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk) and now you want to upgrade to [Google Drive V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php)?   There are a lot of changes your going to have to make I don't think there are any guides on how to do it.   Assuming you are using the Google PHP client library your best option will be to download the library for v3 and start fixing your errors one at a time.    Like i said there are a number of changes in the library mainly title vs name.   That and the library doesn't by default return all the fields your going to have to start using the field parameter.

When you download the library with composer you will be downloading the latest code for use with the Drive API v3.   The Authencation code you have been using probably hasnt changed.   All of the methods you use in drive probably have.  [Drive.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php)

Again there is no upgrade function for this its a completely different API.  There is no way to upgrade it.  You download the new class using composer and change your code as needed

Comment: Yes correct, I am using PHP client library. I installed google api client using composer. Where could I download and place the V3 library?

Comment: if you downloaded it using composer then you have v3.  Last i heard the PHP client library was only building the most resent version of a library so technically you wont download v2 with composer only v3.    Just follow this.   https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php

Comment: Is there a way to find current version using code? Something like echo version or else? 
Thanks

Comment: And actually I am using service account and above link steps are of Oauth, I had tried above before but it simply runs. I don't found any upgrade message after that.

Comment: The auth code should be the same its drive you are updating There is no upgrade function for this its php your going to have to alter your code yourself.    Download the library using composer the auth part hasnt changed just the drive methods you will be using.   This is the source for drive v3 in PHP client library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php

Comment: I checked library files for gdrive as mentioned above and it helps me to fix bug. I was looking for solution to disable the notification of email using code. The exact syntax I found there. Thanks a lot!